# Itemize rows and columns of free command

Tags: bash, shell

I want to know how much memory is being used and free in my system. I ran the **free** command and following is my output
    total     used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      16334624   16199712     134912     372780     333456    4673092
-/+ buffers/cache:   11193164    5141460
Swap:      4194300     806484    3387816

Now I want to get rid of the first column and last line. So, I used this **free | sed -n 1,3p | cut -d " " -f2-** and following is the output

```
       total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
 16334624   16200348     134276     372732     333520    4658336
```

buffers/cache:   11208492    5126132

Now I want to arrange the values in a single line. e.g.
total = 16334624 , used = 16200348 and so on.... and finally buffers/cache used/free = 11208492 /5126132
Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: Kill the first line. On the second line you have the numbers in order. Just print them with appropriate labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk it can be done like this:

```
free | awk 'NR==2 { printf("total = %s\nused = %s\nfree = %s\nshared = %s\nbuff/cache = %s\navailable = %s\n", $2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7)}'
```

- the condition `NR==2` selects only the second line to apply the action on.
- the different fields `$2` to `$7` are the numeric columns from `free` output.
- the `\n` in the `printf` creates a new line.